# Run at Element's Height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some JavaScript to run when the user scrolls past a certain element. In this case, the element is `<span class="accomp"></span>`. The script I put together to handle this works when given a pixel value, but this value may not correspond to the correct area on the page depending on the user's screen resolution, browser, etc.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(window).scrollTop() === $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $( "span.accomp" ).height()) {
      meSpeak.speak('hello world', { pitch: 10, speed: 100 });
   }
});
```

The pixel value based script would have the pixels instead of `$( "span.accomp" ).height()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's [offset()](https://api.jquery.com/offset/).

> *Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the document.*

```
var spoken = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(spoken) return;

    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var elementTop = $("span.accomp").offset().top;

    if(scrollTop >= elementTop){
        meSpeak.speak('hello world', { pitch: 10, speed: 100 });
        spoken = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This works and fixes the problem I experience with another solution in which "hello world" would repeat until you scroll out of the area near below span.accomp . However, what this does is activate when the top of the user's window reaches the element. If possible, can the script be activated when the users first encounters the element, i.e.: their window bottom reaches the span?

Comment: Never mind, as I have managed to do this on my own by reversing the comparison to a less than

Comment: This works fine on its own, however, if you try to use this with multiple spans by changing the variables it triggers them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger event when scroll top reach to scroll of particular element.

```
var elementTop = $(".accomp").offset().top;    
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > elementTop)
    {   
        //add your code here
    }
});
```

**Note:** Please make sure as you are using class for this element, if there is multiple elements with this class result might not be as expected so instead of class use id.

Comment: 'null' is not an object (evaluating '$(".accomp").offset().top')

Comment: plz make sure element with this particular class is available, try using console. as recommended change it to id